# Kerberos Migration Issues - Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, kerberos

We are in the process of migarting the active directory from a Debian server to Ubuntu. LDAP (Slapd), libnss, kerberos, pam, and nfs have been configured. However on client login attempt the server posts Kerberos errors.

Kerberos was migrated by apt installation. We then copied the following files from the old to new server; `krb5.conf`, `krb5.keytab`, `krb5kdc` directory, and `/var/lib/krb5kdc` directory.

```
Sep 17 17:50:01 cs2s krb5kdc[2383]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.0.90: NEEDED_PREAUTH: n.dajnowski@CS for krbtgt/CS@CS, Additional pre-authentication required
Sep 17 17:50:01 cs2s krb5kdc[2383]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.0.90: ISSUE: authtime 1694973001, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}, n.dajnowski@CS for krbtgt/CS@CS
Sep 17 17:50:01 cs2s krb5kdc[2383]: TGS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.0.90: ISSUE: authtime 1694973001, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}, n.dajnowski@CS for host/cs2s.cs@CS
Sep 17 17:50:35 cs2s krb5kdc[2383]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.0.254: NEEDED_PREAUTH: test@CS for krbtgt/CS@CS, Additional pre-authentication required
Sep 17 17:50:35 cs2s krb5kdc[2383]: preauth (encrypted_timestamp) verify failure: Preauthentication failed
Sep 17 17:50:35 cs2s krb5kdc[2383]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.0.254: PREAUTH_FAILED: test@CS for krbtgt/CS@CS, Preauthentication failed
```

The client flashes a black screen and returns to login. We have also tested this on the old server, and receive the following message in the logs on succesful login.

Successful login log from old server:
[image: Successful login log from old server]

I do notice that the old server has `cs2s.cs@CS` rather than `CS@CS`. As I am relatively new to this technology, please could anyone advise on how to configure the new server correctly?

Comment: Keep in mind the service type (like "nfs/" or "krbtgt/" in your example) is still part of the principal name, not merely a logging artifact – I highly doubt that either of the realms actually has anything named _just_ "CS@CS" or "cs2s.cs@CS"; the former is usually "krbtgt/CS" and the latter is probably "nfs/cs2s.cs" and both are expected (they serve different purposes).

Comment: I understand, would this possibly effect the authentication, it seems like the "preauthentication" is failing.

Comment: Also to update, we are able to connect via SSH which is using Kerberos as well. But the clients are still throwing errors

Comment: Have you tried a manual `kinit` with that client's principal? For password-based AS-REQ, "Preauth failed" almost always means the password was wrong (either on input, or the correct input isn't getting to the client-side Kerberos setup).

Comment: @user1686 We haven't tried this and we unfortunately don't have too much experience with Kerberos. Although, ssh login does work through kerberos, where a successful as-req and tgs-req are logged, identical to how it looks when we try log in through the client machine.

Comment: Do you mean SSH login with a password (client sends password and SSH server does all the Kerberos requests; "fake" Kerberos) or do you mean SSH login with GSSAPI (client does the requests and presents a ticket; the "real" Kerberos)?

Comment: I believe it would be the first one. I am just viewing logs on the client machine and on active directory login attempt we get the following. 
`Sep 19 11:05:33 cs2-86 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user n.dajnowski by (uid=0) `
`Sep 19 11:05:33 cs2-86 systemd-logind[1504]: New session 9 of user n.dajnowski.` 
`Sep 19 11:05:33 cs2-86 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user n.dajnowski by (uid=0) `
`Sep 19 11:05:37 cs2-86 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user n.dajnowski `